# USB Boot Interface subclass devices - is it possible to be a keyboard and mouse at the same time

Tags: linux, usb, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

I have a project to use beaglebone black as USB HID keyboard and/or mouse.

Using as starting point [g_hid-demo](https://github.com/csimmonds/g_hid-demo) I'm able to make my BBB to act as keyboard, including for BIOS.
Also I may use it as mouse with Windows 7 host PC, but with different version of hid.c

Is it possible to be a keyboard and mouse at the same time during BIOS editing, using USB Boot Interface subclass? I shall use only one BBB.

IMHO I may create combo HID descriptor using different REPORT_ID for different reports. It should work with modern OS, but it will break USB Boot Interface subclass requirements and will not work with BIOS.